# Laravel : Order by on array

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, eloquent, sql-order-by

I am getting results from the database in the below format.
Now I want to order by on total_price column.
So how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 738644
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 38
                    [total_price] => 110.50
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 738645
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 39
                    [total_price] => 120.50
                )
        )
```

Query of above output is

```
$result = Mymodel::orderBy('data->total_price', 'desc')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: can you show query so someone can help you to solve problem.Also mention data field type

Comment: id and data both are database column and inside data column i m storing whole array.
now i want to order by on total_price which is inside the data column.

Data column has longtext datatype..

Which parameter will come at ?
$result = Mymodel::orderBy(?,'desc')->get()->toArray();

Comment: $result = Mymodel::orderBy('data->total_price', 'desc')->get()->toArray();

Comment: try this and let me know if you have issue

Comment: If you are using json data type colum for the data, then you can use ``orderBy('column->key', 'desc');``

Comment: also if orderby throwing error then enable  'strict' => false, in database.php for mysql and also as suggested by vishnu.it must be in json then only it works or else it wont work

Comment: Or use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods collections which has lot of methods for data manipulation after the query results is fetched.

Comment: Data column has longtext datatype

Comment: @SachinParmar is it still issue

Comment: @JohnLobo thanks for the answer. The issue was column data type.....column data type was not JSON.
I solved the problem after change the data type and using your solution.
$result = Mymodel::orderBy('data->total_price', 'desc')->get()->toArray();

Answer (score 0):

The [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function allows you to pass a custom compare callback function. In there you can compare on your `total_price` field.

Answer (score 0):

[Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) - [The orderBy Method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#orderby):

> The `orderBy` method allows you to sort the results of the query by a given column. The first argument accepted by the `orderBy` method should be the column you wish to sort by, while the second argument determines the direction of the sort and may be either `asc` or `desc`:
>
> ```php
> $users = DB::table('users')
>    ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
>    ->get();
> ```

Try using this:

```php
DB::table('table_name')
   ->orderBy('data->total_price', 'desc')
   ->get()
   ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is stored data in data field is json then

```
$result = Mymodel::orderBy('data->total_price', 'desc')->get()->toArray();
```

or else you can do it using collection

```
$result = Mymodel::all();

$sortedList = $result->sortBy('data.total_price',SORT_REGULAR,true);
$sortedList->all()
```

or For  Asc

```
$result = Mymodel::all();
$sortedList = $result->sortBy('data.total_price');
$sortedList->all()
```